# Run a cygwin built exe file from dos command

Tags: cygwin, command-prompt

I have built a exe (file from .cc) in Cygwin. When I run in Cygwin command prompt it runs nicely, eg

```
$./learn.exe 0.2 0.1
```

gives intended output.

When I invoke cygwin from Windows command prompt and run the same, eg

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "./learn.exe 0.1 0.1"
```

it gives error saying

```
error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

A Cygwin .EXE file should run in the Windows command line. If you are in the directory with `learn.exe`, you can just run it as:

```
learn.exe 0.1 0.1
```

*(If you need lots of arguments or good argument parsing, running in Cygwin Bash is probably better.)*